# Why werl executes the same code in one shell window and freezes in another?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I am trying to solve excercise 5-2 from O'Reilly Erlang Programming book.
My setup is `Win10`, `werl Eshell V7.3`. 
Here are steps to reproduce my problem:

1. `c(frequency).`
2. `frequency:start().`
3. `CTRL-G` -> `S` -> `C` -- to switch to new Erlang shell
4. `frequency:allocate().`
5. `frequency:deallocate(10).`

If I omit point 3 then all goes fine, but when I do everything according to above procedure, then shell gets stuck in line `30` or `43`.

Can someone explain me what am I doing wrong and how to get the exactly same behavior for these two cases: with one, and with two shells?

Module's code (there are two warnings here, but it compiles anyway, I was trying to get deallocation allowed only when called from the same Pid from which allocation was being done):

```
-module(frequency).
-export([start/0, stop/0, allocate/0, deallocate/1]).
-export([init/0]).

%% These are the start functions used to crate and
%% initialize the server.

start() ->
  register(frequency, spawn(frequency, init, [])).

init() ->
  Frequencies = {get_frequencies(), []},
  loop(Frequencies).

% Hard Coded
get_frequencies() -> [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15].

%% The client Functions

stop()          -> call(stop).
allocate()      -> call(allocate).
deallocate(Freq)-> io:format("Calling deallocate~n",[]), call({deallocate, Freq}).

%% We hide all message passing and the message
%% protocol in a functional interface.

call(Message) ->
  Self = self(),
  io:format("Self: ~w~n", [Self]),
  frequency ! {request, Self, Message},
  receive
    {reply, Reply} -> Reply
  end.

%% The Main Loop

loop(Frequencies) ->
  receive 
    {request, Pid, allocate} ->
      {NewFrequencies, Reply} = allocate(Frequencies, Pid),
      reply(Pid, Reply),
      loop(NewFrequencies);
    {request, Pid2, {deallocate, Freq}} ->
      io:format("Dealocate ~w from pid ~w~n", [Freq, Pid2]),
      NewFrequencies = deallocate(Frequencies, Freq), %, Pid2),
      reply(Pid2, ok),
      loop(NewFrequencies);
    {request, Pid, stop} ->
      reply(Pid, ok)
  end.

reply(Pid, Reply) ->
  Pid ! {reply, Reply}.

%% The Internal Help Functions used to allocate and
%% deallocate frequencies.

allocate({[], Allocated}, _Pid) ->
  {{[], Allocated}, {error, no_frequency}};
allocate({[Freq|Free], Allocated}, Pid) ->
  {{Free, [{Freq, Pid}| Allocated]}, {ok, Freq}}.

deallocate({Free, Allocated}, Freq) -> %, Pid) ->
  Response = lists:keysearch(Freq, 1, Allocated),
  io:format("Response: ~w~n", [Response]),
  case Response of
    {value, {Freq, OPid}} ->
        case OPid of
          Pid ->
            NewAllocated = lists:keydelete(Freq, 1, Allocated),
            io:format("Removed freq~n",[]),
            {[Freq|Free], NewAllocated};
          _OtherPid ->
            io:format("Not allowed to remove freq~n",[]),
            {Free, Allocated}
        end;
    _ -> io:format("Not removed freq~n",[]), {Free, Allocated}
  end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not a complete explanation of the problem, but it is linked to the usage of io:format, there is an obscure (obscure for me :o) concept of group leader which is used to determine on which shell an io:format should display a message.

In general, it is not a good idea to display messages in a server loop, which is executed in the server process, it is better to do it in the interface functions executed in the calling process.

I have change your code a little, removing the useless print and corrected the test of pid and it works fine in multiple shells.

```
-module(freq).
-export([start/0, stop/0, allocate/0, deallocate/1]).
-export([init/0]).

%% These are the start functions used to crate and
%% initialize the server.

start() ->
  register(frequency, spawn(freq, init, [])).

init() ->
  Frequencies = {get_frequencies(), []},
  loop(Frequencies).

% Hard Coded
get_frequencies() -> [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15].

%% The client Functions

stop()          -> call(stop).
allocate()      -> call(allocate).
deallocate(Freq)-> io:format("Calling deallocate~n",[]), call({deallocate, Freq}).

%% We hide all message passing and the message
%% protocol in a functional interface.

call(Message) ->
  Self = self(),
  frequency ! {request, Self, Message},
  receive
    {reply, Reply} -> Reply
  end.

%% The Main Loop

loop(Frequencies) ->
  receive 
    {request, Pid, allocate} ->
      {NewFrequencies, Reply} = allocate(Frequencies, Pid),
      reply(Pid, Reply),
      loop(NewFrequencies);
    {request, Pid, {deallocate, Freq}} ->
      {NewFrequencies,Reply} = deallocate(Frequencies, Freq, Pid),
      reply(Pid, Reply),
      loop(NewFrequencies);
    {request, Pid, stop} ->
      reply(Pid, ok)
  end.

reply(Pid, Reply) ->
  Pid ! {reply, Reply}.

%% The Internal Help Functions used to allocate and
%% deallocate frequencies.

allocate({[], Allocated}, _Pid) ->
  {{[], Allocated}, {error, no_frequency}};
allocate({[Freq|Free], Allocated}, Pid) ->
  {{Free, [{Freq, Pid}| Allocated]}, {ok, Freq}}.

deallocate({Free, Allocated}, Freq, Pid) ->
  Response = lists:keysearch(Freq, 1, Allocated),
  case Response of
    {value, {Freq, Pid}} ->
      NewAllocated = lists:keydelete(Freq, 1, Allocated),
      {{[Freq|Free], NewAllocated},removed};
    {value, {Freq, _OtherPid}} ->
      {{Free, Allocated},not_owner};
    _ ->
      {{Free, Allocated},not_found}
  end.
```